# The comma in the textBox

Tags: c#

I would like your help for this problem:
when I create a textbox and type "." the point, I would like it to come out "," the comma.
I've already tried using textBox.Text.Replace but it does not work.
More suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
if (TextBox1_Tex.Contains("."))
{
  TextBox1_Tex.Replace(".", ",");
}
```

Not Work!

Comment: `but it does not work` is not a technical description of a problem, show us your code, what results or errors you get, and any debugging you have done

Comment: But that's what happens already ... if you use the numeric keyboard. This sounds like an XY problem related to localized decimals entry. That's the X. Replacing dots and commas is definitely *NOT* the solution. It may work in one country or one user, it will break for another user in the same country

Comment: Hi Michael, i have edit my question .. so thanks

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?,

Comment: @fhnaseer doesn't matter, the problem would be the same in MVC. Assume a locale, break the app

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so what is the correct way to solve it then?

Comment: Something like `((TextBox) sender).Text` instead of `TextBox1_Tex`?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : hi man, i understand .. how can I solve it ?

Comment: @Ivan if you really really want to guess on the user's behalf, use `CultureInfo.Current` to find out what the proper thousand and decimal separators are, don't hard-code them. Otherwise your textbox may allow a number that gets translated the wrong way

Comment: @Ivan another option is to use a masked edit box that only allows properly formatted numbers. This will make it obvious to the user when an error is made.

Comment: @Ivan another option is to "fix" the format and prevent invalid characters entirely. Internet banking sites for example tell you you can't use thousand separators and only allow a decimal separator. You can do that with a masked box or by cancelling the `KeyDown` event if the wrong key is detected

Comment: @Ivan make it clear to the user what's expected, the same way internet banking sites tell you you should only use digits and the decimal separator.

Comment: @Kanagiotis Kanavos: I will try in the next few hours and I will update you, for now, thank you very much, you are great.

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(".", ",");` The _Replace_ way should work, but you have to handle the return value e.g. assign it to the `Textbox.Text` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code Work perfect and is very fast !!
Thanks to much to every body and to you @ethvlad

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = ((TextBox)sender);
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(".", ",");
    textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(".", ",");
    textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: hehe much shorter than my quicky :) thumbs up

Comment: Work Perfect !!| THX